# Java array of size 0

Tags: java, arrays

So I just discovered that Java allows us to create arrays of size 0.  Does that mean that the array is both empty and full at the same time? I figured this out while working on an array based implementation of a priority queue. Would it be right to say that it is empty and full at the same time when calling methods checking for this? Or should I not allow the creation of an array of size 0? Thanks.

Comment: I'd say that the array is empty, that it has no items.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "full", but an empty array has the property that it is both empty (has size 0) and has every element unequal to `null` (vacuously true).

Comment: Best not to allow arrays of size zero, since they are not dynamic, what purpose would it do you? It's stuck like that, it isn't going to change

Comment: By "full", I mean that the current size of the array is the same as the max size. Which in this is case is true, right?

Comment: Every array is full, because arrays are not dynamic in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Java arrays have no definition of full or of empty. Consider

```
int[] foo = {0};
int[] bar = new int[1];
```

Is `foo` full because it has a value assigned to its only position?

Is `bar` empty because it has no values assigned?

Both arrays are the same, they both have one value stored and in both cases the contain the value 0.

Full implies you can't add any more items, you can never add new items to java arrays, just replace existing items, so either all arrays are full or full does not make sense for a java array. I say it is the second.